# How to change screen orientation in UI Automator Viewer?

Tags: sdk, android-uiautomator

Is there any way to flip the orientation of the screenshot that UI Automator Viewer displays?

My app is always in horizontal orientation. And it seems that UIAV takes the portrait orientation of the tablet and flips it 180 degrees. All the highlights of the elements show up in wrong spots and it is nearly impossible to connect elements to their ids.

I didn't find any settings in UIAV that would change it and there isn't much info that I can find.

Comment: Any Solution found?